# Is there a way in bsub to specify maximum number of jobs per host?

Tags: lsf

My jobs are expensive in terms of internet bandwidth. So I do not want one execution host to run more than two of them parallelly. Is there a way to tell bsub to do so?

```
#BSUB -J myjob[1-100]%10
#BSUB -n 4
```

The way bsub works is that it will schedule all 10 jobs to the first execution host if it has 40(10 x 4) job slots available. I rather want to distribute my 10 parallel jobs over five hosts.

So is there a way in bsub to specify maximum jobs per host from the pool of my parallel jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I found is to use `BSUB -R "order[!slots]"` to select the hosts with most available slots at execution time

The `!` is for sorting at every job within the pool of parallel jobs. If it is omitted: `BSUB -R "order[slots]"`, the sorting will happen only once when the job is submitted.

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=SSWRJV_10.1.0/best_practices/Placing%20jobs%20based%20on%20available%20job%20slots%20of%20hosts.htm